# integral of a vector field in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: integration, differential-geometry

I'm wondering the definition of the integral of a vector field on a hypersurface in R^n.

Here is what I guess, but I did not found it on the internet.

Let $v$ be a vector field on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $S$ be an hypersurface in $\mathbb{R}^n$. I suppose $S$ to be parametrized with $\phi\colon D\to R^n$ where $D$ is an open set in $R^{n-1}$.
I define :

$\int_Sv=\int_D\det(  v\big(\phi(x)\big),\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial s_1},\ldots, \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial s_{n-1}} ) ds_1\ldots ds_{n-1}$.

Is that the correct definition ? I checked that it matches the usual definition for integrating a vector field on a surface in $R^3$ : the integral of the scalar product with the exterior normal which is given by the mix product which is generalized by the determinant.

Second question : integrating a $n-1$ form on $S$. I guess that it is defined as the integral of its Hodge dual. The latter is is a $1$-form that is then converted to a vector field. Then the previous definition works.

Is it right ?
Does one have a link ?dffe

Comment: Since the dimension of S is n-1, it's probably easier to answer your first question using your second question. The integral of an k-form over an k-dimensional manifold has a very natural definition. Given an n-1 form on R^n, you can simply use your map \phi to pull this form back onto S.

Now to your first question: Since you're writing about Hodge duals, you seem to have some extra structure. Starting with the vector, pick the dual one-form, take the Hodge dual and get an n-1 form. Integrate this by pulling it back to S.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Using the fact that the determinant is the only fully antisymmetric form, I should be able to prove that your definition implies the formula I wrote.

Comment: Up to some numerical factors, you should get something like $\int \sqrt{g} \epsilon_{m_1 \dots m_n} v^{m_1} \frac{\partial \phi^{m_2}}{\partial s_1} \dots \frac{\partial \phi^{m_n}}{\partial s_{n-1}} ds_1 \dots ds_{n-1}$. Here $\epsilon_{12\dots n} = +1$ and it is totally antisymmetric. That might well also be the determinant.